# Access Variable variables with an object

Tags: php, arrays, variable-variables

I don't really know how to decribe this problem, so I'm sorry if the title is a bit unclear.

I got an object with array fields. I got the name of these fields stored in a variable and I want to reach an element in one of those array fields. e.g.

```
$field_name = 'array_field';

$object = new stdClass();
$object->array_field= array('this', 'is', 'an', 'array);
```

I know i can access the array with `$object->$field_name`, but now I want to access a value by key in the array while accessing it with the `$field_name` variable. e.g.(that obviously does not work) `$object->$field_name[0]`

Comment: Use arrays, dude. Variable variables are lame.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think, you should use something like the following:

```
$object->{$field_name}[0]
```

It's described in details in "Variable variables" section of PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

BTW, according to my experience, such way of fields manipulation may lead to code obscurity - I'd recommend to use associative arrays, if possible.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I guess I'm blind because I couldn't find it there or I just didn't know what to look for

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$object->{$field_name}[0]
```